# What's the OST that plays when Jiren powers up at the end of Dragon Ball Super episode 126?

Tags: music, dragon-ball-super

So there's this really cool theme that plays when Jiren powers up at the end of episode 126. I've just been trying to get the name of it for ages. I know I'm really really late but still. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The name of this OST is *Memories of time* ! It is composed by Norihito SUMITOMO and can be listened to by this [YouTube link (Recreated by Pokemix92)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ji6gnw-e1888) .